# xslt matching and stripping

Tags: xslt

I have a XML structure like this, just some valid XML structure mixed with HTML tags. I am trying to match `<p>MyHeader</p>` in the section and set it to empty.

That is after running the XSLT on this structure, i don't want to print the `<p>MyHeader</p>` tag.

```
<abstract>
<section>
<p>MyHeader</p>

<p> other content in section </p>
<h1> other content in section </h1>

</section>
</abstract>
```

Here's what I am trying in the XSL

```
<xsl:template match="abstract/section/p">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="text() ='MyHeader'"></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:apply-templates /></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

any ideas on what's wrong with my code above? I dont see `<p>MyHeader</p>` tag being stripped out.

Comment: At first sight, this should work, so I think the problem may lie in another part of your XSLT. Some other template could be matching the **p** element, for example. Could you post your full XSLT file, if possible? Thank you!

Comment: I agree the samples as posted should work but I would strongly suggest to shorten the template to `<xsl:apply-templates select="abstract/section/p[. = 'MyHeader']"/>`, that suffices to remove the element and your `xsl:otherwise` is done by the built in templates anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <xsl:template match="abstract/section/p">
>         <xsl:choose>
>             <xsl:when test="text() ='MyHeader'"></xsl:when>
>             <xsl:otherwise><xsl:apply-templates /></xsl:otherwise>
>         </xsl:choose>
> </xsl:template>
>
>  what's wrong with my code
> ```

Nothing wrong with the code shown -- the problem is in the code you haven't shown to us.

**Guessing**:

- The template isn't selected for execution.
- There is an explicit `<xsl:copy-of>` selecting this `p` element.

**Recommendation: just use**:

```
<xsl:template match="abstract/section/p[.='MyHeader']"/>
```